# Getting error on deploying the process definition in activiti-rest using java code

Tags: rest, alfresco, activiti

Hi all i am trying to deploy process definiton in activiti-rest by using java rest.But getting error as 'Exception in thread "main" Bad Request (400)'.I have tried a lots in google but not found any solution for that.Please help me where is the actual fault in my code.Find below my java code and errors.

**My Errors**

```html
  
Starting the internal HTTP client
Exception in thread "main" Bad Request (400) - The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax
 at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.doError(ClientResource.java:590)
 at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handleInbound(ClientResource.java:1153)
 at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1048)
 at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:1023)
 at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.post(ClientResource.java:1485)
 at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.post(ClientResource.java:1424)
 at com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.Activiti_Rest_BuyEconomyOrBusinsessClassTIcket.TicketClass.createdeployment(TicketClass.java:40)
 at com.bizruntime.activiti.rest.Activiti_Rest_BuyEconomyOrBusinsessClassTIcket.Ticke_Test.main(Ticke_Test.java:13)
```

**My Java Code**

```html
/**
*Client Resource
*/
private static ClientResource getClientResource(String uri){
 ClientResource resource=new ClientResource("http://localhost:8431/activiti-rest/service");
 resource.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC,kermit,kermit);
 return resource;
}

/**
 * Creating Deployment
 */
public static JSONObject createdeployment(){
 String uri=REST_URI+"/repository/deployments";
 log.debug("uri(Create Deploymnet):: "+uri);
 JSONObject my_data=new JSONObject();
 try {
  my_data.put("name","BuyTicket.bpmn20.xml");
  Representation response=getClientResource(uri).post(my_data);
  JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response.getText());
  if(object!=null){
    log.info("Deployed Successfully.....");
    return object;
  }
  
 } catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cfr. http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_create_a_new_deployment: the body should not be a json multipart/form-data file that is a bpmn20.xml file (or a .zip in case of multiple files)